gamma family glmmTMB models give error: Error in fitTMB(TMBStruc) : negative log-likelihood is NaN at starting parameter values
This happens for Gamma models:
> testdata<-data.frame(DV=1+sample(0:100),
+                      pred=sample(-50:50))
> hmod<-glmmTMB(formula=DV~pred,
+               data=testdata,family=Gamma)
Error in fitTMB(TMBStruc) : 
  negative log-likelihood is NaN at starting parameter values

This happens for ziGamma models too:
> testdata<-data.frame(DV=sample(0:100),
+                      pred=sample(-50:50))
> hmod<-glmmTMB(formula=DV~pred,
+               ziformula=~pred,
+               data=testdata,family=ziGamma)
Error in fitTMB(TMBStruc) : 
  negative log-likelihood is NaN at starting parameter values

The model manages to converge when the continuous part of the model is just an intercept, though it still produces NAs:
> hmod<-glmmTMB(formula=DV~1,
+               ziformula=~pred,
+               data=testdata,family=ziGamma)
Warning messages:
1: In (function (start, objective, gradient = NULL, hessian = NULL,  :
  NA/NaN function evaluation
2: In (function (start, objective, gradient = NULL, hessian = NULL,  :
  NA/NaN function evaluation
3: In (function (start, objective, gradient = NULL, hessian = NULL,  :
  NA/NaN function evaluation
4: In (function (start, objective, gradient = NULL, hessian = NULL,  :
  NA/NaN function evaluation

I've reinstalled Matrix, TMB, and glmmTMB from source - did not work.
Downgrading Matrix to 1.6-2 was suggested on an older post with the same error but I would like to avoid that, as it would break a lot of other packages I use (like lme4). What should I do?
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.utf8    

time zone: Europe/Vienna
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] glmmTMB_1.1.10 lmerTest_3.1-3 lme4_1.1-35.5  Matrix_1.7-1   mgcv_1.9-1     nlme_3.1-164  
 [7] ggplot2_3.5.1  stringr_1.5.1  dplyr_1.1.4    magrittr_2.0.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] sandwich_3.1-1      utf8_1.2.4          generics_0.1.3      stringi_1.8.4       lattice_0.22-6     
 [6] grid_4.4.1          estimability_1.5.1  mvtnorm_1.3-2       this.path_2.5.0     survival_3.6-4     
[11] multcomp_1.4-26     fansi_1.0.6         scales_1.3.0        TH.data_1.1-2       codetools_0.2-20   
[16] numDeriv_2016.8-1.1 reformulas_0.4.0    Rdpack_2.6.1        cli_3.6.3           rlang_1.1.4        
[21] rbibutils_2.3       munsell_0.5.1       splines_4.4.1       withr_3.0.2         tools_4.4.1        
[26] nloptr_2.1.1        coda_0.19-4.1       minqa_1.2.8         colorspace_2.1-1    boot_1.3-30        
[31] vctrs_0.6.5         R6_2.5.1            zoo_1.8-12          lifecycle_1.0.4     emmeans_1.10.5     
[36] MASS_7.3-60.2       pkgconfig_2.0.3     pillar_1.9.0        gtable_0.3.6        glue_1.8.0         
[41] Rcpp_1.0.13-1       tibble_3.2.1        tidyselect_1.2.1    rstudioapi_0.17.1   xtable_1.8-4       
[46] TMB_1.9.15          compiler_4.4.1 


From https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#gamma-glmms you could try Gamma(link="log")

That worked, thanks!
Ben Bolker states there that the Gamma distribution with inverse link is problematic. What puzzles me though, is the fact that the equivalent model works fine in base r:
hmod<-glm(formula=DV~pred,data=testdata,family=Gamma)

glmmTMB is a lot more flexible so i'd assume a far more complex algo under the hood. Bu perhaps, it could be differences in optimiser defaults e.g. the start values. In this case along the lines f start=list(beta=c(1,0)). Hopefully, you get a better answer from someone .

For Gamma models I've had good experiences using Bayesian models for fitting. See packages brms or rstanarm, they make that rather easy.

See also https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/1089
